# Specify local SSL certificate for https host using PHP cURL?

Tags: php, curl, https, certificate, certificate-authority

I want to connect to an https host using [PHP cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), but I don't want to use the certificate returned by the host or its CA path.

As I have the certificate locally, I'd like to use the local file instead of the certificate returned by the host and not rely on the CAs.

I’ve studied and searched and tried a number of things, but nothing is working except the normal default path, which gets the certificate from the host and follows the CA path.

Changing the existing host certificate is not an option.

Comment: It might help if we knew why you're trying to skip the default cert. Is this just a speed issue on your cURL calls?

Comment: I don’t want to have to trust or reference the CA. I have actually developed a workaround, which is to use the default method and, once successful, compare the certificate that cURL got from the server to my local copy. I’d rather a more direct means, though, if cURL already supports it.

Comment: I don't really understand your reasoning: when you are using a certificate that was signed and issued by a CA, you are already trusting the CA that it has verified that the owner of the certificate is who he says he is.

Comment: No, I don’t necessarily know that it was signed by a CA. I know that it _says_ that it was signed by some CA. Even if it was signed by the same CA, I don’t know that the certificate is otherwise genuine. I know that the copy I have is genuine. In other words, this is for a site that I have taken even greater steps to confirm the identity than the CA probably has.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you. Either I got your question wrong or you have a fundamental misunderstanding regarding SSL.

You have to use the host's certificate (which is a public key), otherwise the host won't understand what you're sending.

Comment: From the original query: “...I have the certificate locally...”.
Downvoted for missing that and for providing no answer. (This belongs as a comment to the original query.)

Comment: @danorton Well, what seems clear to you as the one posing the question is not necessarily clear for the people reading it. For me it was not clear that your local certificate is equivalent to the one "returned by the host", because you specifically mentioned that you do not want to use that one. This is why I came to the conclusion that you probably got something wrong. To me this is a valid answer.